# Recurring Payments Library - Java or Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, payment-gateway, payment-processing, recurring-billing

We use Exact Payment Technology at work for processing payments (our current setup uses their Hosted Payment solution).  I've been tasked with adding the ability to do recurring payments.  Exact Payment handles this by returning a token from the hosted payment page that you can then later send to process a future payment.  However, the recurring part is all up to us to code.  Before I create something from scratch I was wondering if there's anything out there already, ideally in Java or Groovy.  It would have to allow scheduling of payments (possibly by adding a database entry that it then reads, or some other way), processing the payments (via some way that is adaptable to various payment processors), and logging all events so accounting can keep things reconciled.

Comment: Basically, you've got to code a business rule scheduler. Why are you considering Groovy? To what you have to add this functionality? a server? an in-house app?

Answer (score 0):

See related question: [Is there an open-source solution that allows me to create subscription based payments using Stripe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220732/is-there-an-open-source-solution-that-allows-me-to-create-subscription-based-pay)

There are at least two open-source recurring engines that I know of: [JBilling](http://www.jbilling.com/) and [Kill Bill](http://killbill.io/subscription-billing/).

I don't think Exact Payment Technology is integrated with any of them but it's just a matter of writing a small connector to the gateway (i.e. a Java interface to implement).