# Is there an open-source solution that allows me to create subscription based payments using Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm looking for an open-source invoicing platform that allows me to use Stripe to auto-bill a client each month. [Anchor](http://theanchorapp.com/) looks good but it does not provide subscription based payments. Is there a free app that can do this?

Comment: It may not be what you need but you could just use stripe dashboard if you need a simple way of doing this.

Comment: Here's a [list](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations#invoicing) of all of them that Stripe knows about. Some of them may be open source. Or [these](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations#recurring-payments) for recurring payments.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at:

- [JBilling](http://www.jbilling.com/) (AGPL v3). I don't know if it supports Stripe but you can add your own integration by writing a custom plugin
- [Kill Bill](http://killbill.io/subscription-billing/) (Apache License v2), which has already a Stripe plugin